# Layout bug in new documentation review design

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, design

The recently redesigned layout for documentation review has a bug with the Review status/edit comment sticking to the top of the lower window and scrolling over the rest of the page.

In chrome 58, this is the initial view

[image]

Then as the page scrolls the "Review completed 5hrs ago" box scrolls with the page, like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing the background style there, sorry about that.

Fix going live with the next production build.